# Hw do i render a partial in rails 3.0 using ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I want to use ajax in my application here is my problem :

I have a income voucher controller and model which receives incomes from various sources.
for this i have a payment_mode model with card, cheque and internet_banking payment option here is my code:

From model:
**income_voucher**

```
 class IncomeVoucher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :payment_mode, :foreign_key => :voucher_id
 end
```

** payment_mode:**

```
class PaymentMode < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :transactionable, :polymorphic => true
 belongs_to :receipt_voucher    
end
```

**card_payment:**

```
class CardPayment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :payment_mode, :as => :transactionable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

similar in cheque and Internet banking model .

My controller:
**income_vouchers_controller:**

```
class IncomeVouchersController < ApplicationController
def new
    @income_voucher = IncomeVoucher.new
    @invoices = current_company.invoices
    @income_voucher.build_payment_mode

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @income_voucher }
    end
  end
 def create
    @income_voucher = IncomeVoucher.new(params[:income_voucher])

   transaction_type = params[:transaction_type]
    payment_mode = nil
    if transaction_type == 'cheque'
      payment = ChequePayment.new(params[:cheque_payment])
    payment.amount = @income_voucher.amount
    elsif transaction_type == 'card'
      payment = CardPayment.new(params[:card_payment])
    payment.amount = @income_voucher.amount
    elsif transaction_type == 'ibank'
      payment = InternetBankingPayment.new(params[:internet_banking_payment])
    payment.amount = @income_voucher.amount
    else
      payment = CashPayment.new
    payment.amount = @income_voucher.amount
    end
    payment_mode = PaymentMode.new
    payment_mode.transactionable = payment

    @income_voucher.payment_mode = payment_mode
    respond_to do |format|
      if @income_voucher.save

        format.html { redirect_to(@income_voucher, :notice => 'Income voucher was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @income_voucher, :status => :created, :location => @income_voucher }
      else

        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @income_voucher.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

In my form i did this:

```
<%= render :partial => "card_payment" %>
<%= render :partial => "cheque_payment" %>
<%= render :partial => "internet_banking_payment" %>
```

friend till now i am rendering my partials simply as we do  in rails but now i want to do this using ajax. I hope you guy's have done this earlier.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple:

In your javascript (on page, for example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "your_path",
  data: {  //params if needed
    your_param_name: param,
    your_param_name2: param2
  }
});
```

In your routes:

```
match 'your_path' => 'y_controller#y_method'
```

In y_controller:

```
def y_method
  # do smth with params[:your_param_name] if needed
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

In your y_method.js.erb:

```
$('#your-div').html('<%= raw escape_javascript render("cart_payment") %>'); //instead html() may be append()
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexeev Mikhail i did this but i have three partials which i want to render on radio button select

Comment: Will you please please tell me what changes do i need in my _form.html.erb file

Comment: If in your js method, which contains your ajax, get selected radio and send that as param

`data: { type: $('form input[type=radio]:checked').val() }`

in your view switch type-param:

`<% case params[:type] %>

  <% when '1' %>

    <%= render ... %>

...

<% end %>`

Comment: i have done this but nothing happened and in console server i got a message                                                          "   Processing by IncomeVouchersController#income_voucher_partial as Parameters: {"$('form in{"type"=>"radio]:checked').val()=cash"}, "type"=>"cash"}", but nothing render

Comment: Thanks my console error has been solved, but no form partial renders yet here is my get message "Started GET "/income_vouchers/income_voucher_partial?$(%27form%20input[type=radio]:checked%27).val()=cash&type=cash""

Comment: ravindra, why in your address appeared

`?$(%27form%20input[type=radio]:checked%2‌​7).val()=cash` ?

You must get smth like:

`/income_vouchers/income_voucher_partial?type=cash`

Activate your console in browser and see in response of GET method.

Comment: yes i get "/income_voucher_partial? partial = cash & type = cash", here partial is my  variable name

Comment: Hey @Alexeev Mikhail is their any problem in my partial i have <tr> tag in my partials and rendering the partial in <div> tag

Comment: here is my script file code "$(document).ready(function(){
$("#check").click(function(){
 var payment = $('form input[type= radio]:checked').val()
  $.ajax({
   url : "/income_vouchers/income_voucher_partial?payment="+payment,
   data: { 
          type:payment
        }
 
 });
 
 });
 }); "
i don't able to figure out the error